# Firestore query to variable to populate shared preferences

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, sharedpreferences

New to Flutter, and although I've been around code for many years, this is my first time actually developing.  I've been trying to figure out how to query the Cloud Firestore and map one of those properties to a shared preference. Since my app is talking to the cloud firestore when a user logs in anyway, I feel like I can update my shared preferences with a few fields that will save me from having to call firestore everytime I want to retrieve that piece of information.

I created a class that represents the collection layout in the firestore

```
class FirestoreUser {
  FirestoreUser(this.aboutMe, this.nickname);

  final String aboutMe;
  final String nickname;


  factory FirestoreUser.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    if (data == null) {
      return null;
    }
    final String aboutMe = data['aboutMe'];
    final String nickname = data['nickname'] ?? '';
    return FirestoreUser(aboutMe, nickname);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'aboutMe': aboutMe,
      'nickname': nickname,

    };
  }
}
```

I also have a function that writes data to the Firestore collection. That works just fine.

What I'm having a hard time with is how do I query for "aboutMe" in the collection above? I'm using 
a provider to get the uid, but how do I do something like this:

```
aboutMe = Firestore.query.tothatdocument
```

Here's what I have been working on so far:

```
final user = Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false);
final firestore = Provider.of<FirestoreService>(context, listen:false);
final firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('id', isEqualTo: firebaseUser.uid).getDocuments();
final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

And I want to do something like this:

`prefs.setString('aboutMe', 'thatAboutMeVariable);`

Is this possible? I think I'm missing capturing the stream as a snapshot? but not to sure.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new class with functions to retrieve the fields that I wanted. I then assigned a variable to the results of that function.

Here's the call:

```
aboutMe = await FirestoreUserService(id:  widget.id).getAboutMeFromFirestore();
```

Here's the class and function:

```
     class FirestoreUserService {
    
        FirestoreUserService({@required this.id});
        final FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
        CollectionReference users;
        String aboutMe;
    
        Future getAboutMeFromFirestore() async {
          DocumentSnapshot ds = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(id).get();
          aboutMe = ds.data()['aboutMe'];
          //print('\nFirestore aboutMe is value: $aboutMe');
          return aboutMe;
        }
}
```